# Accumulo and MapReduce: Unable to locate bins for specified ranges

Tags: mapreduce, accumulo

I'm writing a MapReduce job that gets its input from Accumulo. I'm using AccumuloInputFormat with a RegExFilter. When I run the job, it connects to Accumulo with no problems, but after the connection is established, I see the following warning ad infinitum:

```
WARN mapreduce.InputFormatBase: Unable to locate bins for specified ranges. Retrying.
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with Accumulo as I can scan my table of interest from the shell. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to check the Accumulo monitor and make sure that there are no unassigned tablets. Either your tablet server died, or for some other reason you have unassigned tablets. This would be the most obvious reason as to why you were repeatedly seeing that warning.

Answer (score 0):

Could also be that ZK is down, so accumulo can't know where it's data is.

Comment: ZooKeeper is only used to find the Accumulo root table, none of the user-tables. If the locations for user tablets can't be achieved, that's an Accumulo-level operation, not a ZooKeeper one.